# Data visualisation: Drawing occurence of value in grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-visualization, key-value

Right now I'm trying to draw a rect on a canvas for each occurence of the element in my array. For the positioning I use the longitude and latitude values of the elements in the array.

Let's say that I want to draw the occurence of elements in NYC in a square grid.

Since the latitude and longitude of those elements just varies slightly I'll have to use scaling to give the rects that I want to draw a bit of space *(So it doesn't look like a chaotic cluster)*. 
Therefore I multiplied the x and y of `rect()` with a factor.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var lat = array[i].latitude;
    var lon = array[i].longitude;

    ctx.rect(lat*10,(lon+200)*2, 4, 4);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

My array looks something like this and contains 100.000 objects:

```
var modified_array = 
[{"city":"NYC","longitude":-73.935242,"latitude":40.730610},
 {"city":"NYC","longitude":-74.044502,"latitude":40.689247}]
```

Right now it doesn't display anything and I don't see what I did wrong …

Am I using the right approach for drawing a (square) grid?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works exactly as is for me. To test it I specified an array of the form:

```
var array = [{latitude: 1.2, longitude: 1.3}]
```

Maybe it is your html or the array does not have the format you expect.

Check this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwyLMg